# Spring JPA optimize transitive @ManyToOne fetching

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

In my project I have three Entities like this:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    private int id;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, optional = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private A a;
}

@Entity
public class C {
    @Id
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, optional = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private B b;
}
```

As you can see, `C` has a tansitive ManyToOne-Relationship with `A`.
Now, I want to fetch all `C`s with a specific `A` using my `JpaRepository`:

```
public interface CRepository extends JpaRepository<C, Integer> {
    List<C> findAllByBA(A a);
}
```

Which results in the following Hibernate sql query (which is fine):

> Hibernate: select ... from c c0_ cross join b b1_ where c0_.b_id=b1_.id and b1_.a_id=?

But afterwards I get another query for each distinct `B` (which can be several thousand, so is not fine):

> Hibernate: select ... from b b0_ inner join a a1_ on b0_.a_id=a1_.id where b0_.id=?

---

Obviously, **this could be solved with a single join** using all three tables. But **how do I tell Hibernate** to do that without losing the convenience of abstraction with `JpaRepository`?

Comment: Why not just use @query annotation ?

Comment: @gtosto I haven't used `@query` before. How does it work with `@ManyToOne`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The additional, unwanted, queries are caused by the fact that the association is eager. To avoid loading the Bs, you should make the association lazy:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch: FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, optional = false)
```

I generally make every association lazy. When you're not interested in Bs, or do not know in advance if loading Bs is necessary, making the association lazy avoids loaded them. And if you know you want the Bs to be loaded along with the Cs, then you just load them explicitly in your query:

```
@Query("select c from C c left join fetch c.b where c.b.a = ?")
```

Comment: "I generally make every association lazy." No! That's a really bad idea and makes no sense here because you can use join fetch even if the relationship is EAGER. If you make all associations LAZY you will end up with a lot of initialization code. Additionally LAZY only works for non-optional ToOne references.

Comment: Sorry, not a solution for me. I'm using the entities in a vaadin UI, and I don't want to pollute the UI with hibernate sessions.

Comment: The Query("select c from C c join fetch c.b where c.b.a = ?") should work for your case without LAZY. Just try it. Otherwise the question is if you really want Entities or if you better use DTO. Maybe you explain a bit more what you want to achieve.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli the thing is, I know what I'm doing. So I prefer not loading something I don't need by default (making things eager is precisely what causes a lot of useless queries and initializations), and use join fetch to load things efficiently when I need them. And no, lazy works fine with optional toOne associations.

Comment: @F43nd1r could you clarify what you mean by "I don't want to pollute the UI with hibernate sessions". Why do you think loading an association using a join fetch and letting hibernate loading it with EAGER makes any difference?

Comment: @JBNizet a join fetch is a single select against table a. Hibernates eager results in a number of selects equal to the number of Bs against table a. I can't imagine that being efficient.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm sure you know what you are doing but you are probably an ORM expert. What I see in real-world is a naive way of using ORM and this leads to performance problems. ORM is a leaky abstraction and needs a lot of experience.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I can agree with that. But IMHO, using EAGER leads to worse performance than using lazy.

Comment: @F43nd1r agreed, which is precisely why my answer suggests using a join fetch.

Comment: @JBNizet I'll probably end up using a join fetch. However, your answer suggests that a join fetch has lazy loading as a prerequisite, which is untrue. Also, I brought your answer back to 0. If you rewrite it to make clear lazy loading is completely optional for it, I'll accept it.

Comment: Sorry if it gave that impression. Most of your question is about why many queries are executed to get Bs, and how to avoid them. Making the association lazy allows avoiding them. For this use-case, and for all the other use-cases where you're not interested in Bs. Now, if you actually want the Bs to be loaded, the join fetch allows doing that, in a single query.